# tvOS Login screen Done button callback

Tags: authentication, uitextfield, tvos, apple-tv

tvOS provides a very simple and basic way to login user. Just put some text fields like email and password field and when you press on that I will open a new screen where you can enter first email then press `Continue` and then you enter the password and then there is a `Done` button.

I am facing a hard time in figuring out that when done is pressed how can I get the callback for that. So that I start authenticating the user credentials.

Comment: How you calling API stuff? Have you used delegate ?

Comment: No i have not used any delegate. Which API stuff you are talking about?

Comment: How you are authenticating user ? I hope you will be having API call

Comment: It is some call to my own server. But the question is how i can get the data for example username and password when i press done button which is provided by apple UI when you are filling the password field and after that there is no other text field on that VC

Comment: It is same like iOS, When u press done get usernameTextfield.text and passwordTextfield.text and send it ur server for validation

Comment: Yes i know that but in this case i need to have a separate button or action which will trigger a function and then in that function i read username.text and password.text. But my question is that how i get a callback or function is triggered when i press Done in Apple provided UI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96532/discussion-between-yohan-and-madu).